# EWS error: "The request failed schema validation: The required attribute 'FieldURI' is missing."

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm using EWS to bind to a specific message in my mailbox on Exchange. All was going fine until I added an extended property to my request. How do I set this 'FieldURI' property? (which none of the objects involved seem to have!)

```
                Dim expCP = New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common, "My Custom Prop Name", MapiPropertyType.String)
                prpPropsToLoadUpdateMessages.Add(ItemSchema.ExtendedProperties)
                prpPropsToLoadUpdateMessages.Add(expCP)
                Dim itmMessage As Item = Item.Bind(ews, New ItemId(strUniqueId), prpPropsToLoadUpdateMessages)
```

The 4th line of this snippet throws the error. I haven't included the code I used to define `prpPropsToLoadUpdateMessages` because it's about 100 lines of adding *almost* every property in `ItemSchema`.

TIA,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/207be791-0ae7-4fd1-b9a8-90e83249b9f8.

The problem was I was using `DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Common` when it should have been `DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings`

Comment: you should accept your answer so question would show up as solved in searches